# Viewpager page width more than Screen width in Android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, android-viewpager

is it possible set view pager page width more than screen width ?? 
i am loading images in view pager pages, I can't compromise with images quality and one image is big enough than device width. i don't want to resize images. i am loading hundred of images with size more than screen width.
so, is it possible to take view pager page width more than device screen width ?? 
any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/14/android-tip-viewpager-with-protruding-children/ Possibly helpful

Comment: i want to set one page width more than device's screen width.